# Navigation Bar Flicker with Custom Transition on iPhone 4 and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios7

I created a custom transition (UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) in iOS7 and all seemed to work well. However, I noticed on iPhone 4 and iPad (when displaying as an iPhone app) that it have a weird flicker bug at the end of the transition. Has anyone else encountered this problem? I'm not sure if it's an iOS bug or a problem with my code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jl7qzgvfxhI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I'm seeing navigation bar issues on 7.[REDACTED] with custom animated transitions but not on 7.0.X. What iOS version?

Comment: 7.0.4 — however I removed the custom transition tonight and the issue is still there — it must be the collection view. :/